# C++ throw syntax

Tags: c++

I have a general question regarding the syntax of throwing an object.  Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct bad { };

void func() {
    throw bad;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    try {
        func();
    } catch(bad) {
        printf("Caught\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile (g++ 4.4.3), as the 'throw' line must be replaced with:

```
throw bad();
```

Why is this?  If I'm creating a stack-allocated bad, I construct it like so:

```
bad b;
// I can't use 'bad b();' as it is mistaken for a function prototype
```

I've consulted Stroustrup's book (and this website), but was unable to find any explanation for what seems to be an inconsistency to me.

Comment: `bad b;` != `bad;` just as `bad b();` != `bad();`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
throw bad;
```

doesn't work because `bad` is a data type, a structure (`struct bad`). You cannot throw a data type, you need to throw an object, which is an instance of a data type.

You need to do:

```
bad obj;
throw obj;
```

because that creates an object `obj` of `bad` structure and then throws that object.

Comment: He could also do it like throw bad(); right? Is this in any way wrong?

Comment: I realize this - I just found syntax inconsistent with how stack-allocated objects are constructed.  I see everyone else seems to be of the opposite opinion, so I'll just accept it and move on.  Thanks.

Comment: @FailedDev: Not wrong at all,The rule is *throw by value, catch by reference*, just `throw bad()` should work too,it generates a temporary and throws that by value.

Comment: @KyleMorgan: But it's not inconsistent at all.  `bad` is a type, `b` is an instance of `bad`.  They are different things.  Consider `bad b = bad()`.  Does it seem more consistent now?

Comment: @Als: Not really. My gripe is more with the syntax of calling the default constructor for immediate objects, I suppose.  It seems clunky to me to have to omit the parentheses in order to distinguish between an object declaration and a function prototype.  Thus, it seems I should be able to omit the parentheses in a throw (as per the original question), and the compiler would be able to infer that I want to throw an instance of bad using the default constructor (as throwing a type doesn't make sense anyway).

Comment: @KyleMorgan: Ah,Okay, that is how it works though.With Language semantics We can't really do much but have to accept whats been provided.

Comment: To be clear, the thing that must follow the `throw` must be an *expression*.  A type identifier is not a valid expression on it's own.  Applying the `()` changes the meaning of the tokens to be an *expression which invokes the default constructor for the type identified by `bad`*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to throw an instance of the struct.

```
void func() {
    bad b;
    throw b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `throw`'s argument is an object, not a type. Declaring a variable as `bad b` is of the syntax `[type] [object_name];`. And type != instance.

Comment: Does not have to be strictly an object.  It can be a literal (i.e. `throw 1;`)

Comment: @MichaelPrice: the thing to the right side of the `throw` keyword is an _expression_.  `throw 1;` is equlivalent to `int t(1); throw t;`  The thing being thrown is always an object.

Comment: @MooingDuck - You should see my comment on the other answer. I will grant that an the thing being thrown is always an object (since something declared as an `int` is an object of a primitive type), but the assertion that `int t(1); throw t;` is equivalent to `throw 1;` depends on optimization.  After running an experiment on the clang demo compiler (http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi) with optimizations disabled, the generated code is not the same.  Functionally the same, but not the same.

Comment: @MichaelPrice: I didn't think about how becoming an `lvalue` would change things.  `throw int(1);` should be the same though, right?

Comment: @MooingDuck - It looks like `throw int(1);` is equivalent to `throw 1;`, at least from look at clang's output. Luckily, the optimizer made the other situation equivalent too though.